# Can hydrogen plasma reduce carbon dioxide?

Tags: redox, hydrogen, environmental-chemistry, plasma-chemistry

There are several studies describing usage of hydrogen plasma to reduce metal oxides. This is not yet widely adopted in industry, but it is of interest for environmental reasons (such as described in [Sabat et al. 2013](http://link.springer.com/10.1007/s11090-013-9484-2)).

I was wondering if the same could be done with carbon dioxide. If not, why not? Is there a way to calculate which oxides can be reduced this way?

Comment: The big question isn't whether it is *possible* but whether it cost a small enough amount of energy to be worth doing.

Comment: Not really, because if it isn't possible, then the question of energy efficiency isn't relevant.

Comment: Of course it's possible, but why would one want to do so?